# Image hovering results in showing some text

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, hover

i want to make my text #gmail_info display when you hover image #gmail, but i have little problem, have a look on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jmvoqrxf/

```
<h2>Kontakt</h2>
<div id="gmail"><img src="gmail.jpg" alt="Gmail"/></div>
<div id="info">
    <p id="gmail_info">Rostikcze@gmail.com</p>
</div>
#gmail:hover #gmail_info {
    display: block;
}
#gmail_info {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
```

Comment: For a start, the image doesn't exist local to jsfiddle. What is the problem, what can you not do?

Comment: i know, but it doesnt matter, i need help with code, no with image, just imagine it and give me a help please..)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with jQuery. Minimal change in your css. I used `visibility: hidden;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/vakn3yfp/

```
$("#gmail").hover(function () {
    $("#gmail_info").css("visibility","visible");
      },
      function () {
        $("#gmail_info").css("visibility","hidden");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your html, you can do as follows.

```css
#gmail_info {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
#gmail:hover #gmail_info {
  display: block;
}
img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Kontakt</h2>
<div id="gmail">
  <img src="gmail.jpg" alt="Gmail" />
  <div id="info">
    <p id="gmail_info">Rostikcze@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of the css `display` property, you could also use `visibility`.

```
#gmail_info {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#gmail:hover #gmail_info {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The difference to `display: none;` is, that `visibility: hidden;` will still use the same space as when it would be visible.